# Capistrano: Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I tried deploying my rails application using Capistrano but after the deployment has finished, I get the following error:

```
 Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources
```

I have tried adding  Gem 'rake' to my Gemfile and redeploying and have tried setting the rvm path.

Comment: It seems multiple version of rakes are installed. You need to uninstall other rake version and keep rake 10.5.0

Answer (score 1):

```
1) gem install bundler
2) bundle install
```

try to run the code after these 2 commands